# how to force a figure to appear in a particular place in report

Tags: floats

I'm a new user for latex, I would be grateful if you could help me to force a figure to appear in a particular place in report, my code I've already used is:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{fig_ch1}
\caption{Types of DG}
\label{fig_ch1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text

Comment: Where is this mysterious "particular place"? Please elaborate a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your document and specify what you want to do. Torbjørn's linked question is a very good resource for figure placement.

Comment: With `\begin{figure}[htbp]` you'll allow the figure to be placed here or at least at a suitable position nearby.

Comment: the _only_ reason to use the `figure` environment is to mark the content as a float that is not part of the main text flow and can be moved to help with page breaking,